# PHP access object property through constant's value

Tags: php, object, constants

I have a Player class which has properties: $infantry, $vehicles and $air.

When battling players, I don't know which property is being used as an array which holds the properties to be used is shuffled to create a random order.

I try to use this, but it doesn't work. Strangely it doesn't give me empty property error so I assume it's pointing to some property:

```
<?php

$typeOrder = array(_INF_, _VEH_, _AIR_); // _INF_ const = "infantry" etc
$turnOrder = $typeOrder;
shuffle($turnOrder);
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
   $attType = $turnOrder[$i];
   print $p1->$attType;
}

?>
```

How do I properly access a property with the value held in a constant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work - as long as `$p1->infantry` etc exist. What error does PHP give you exactly?

By the way, have a look at [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Comment: OK thanks Rijk. It turns out all properties in player are being held apart from those three. Looks like the above isn't the problem.

Comment: I found the problem, but don't know how to solve it. When I load the players' properties from an SQL query, it seems that $this->_INF_ = $data[_INF_] is different from $this->infantry = $data[_INF_] Do you know why? It's as though the class makes a new property with the constant's name instead of just using the property which the constant holds :s

Comment: Well, yeah, that's exactly what's happening. `$this->_INF_` accesses the actual property `$_INF_`, while `$data[_INF_]` 'evaluates' the constant to its actual value. It's because in the last example PHP expects a string, so that's how it knows it's a constant. `$property = _INF_; $this->$property = $data[ _INF_ ];` should work for you.

Comment: Works fine now, thanks for clearing that up. Got myself all confused :D